# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable, store

when I trying to copy table data to an array, this run time exception got. And I used

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dataValues, columnNames);
jtable.setModel(model);
```

I used `setModel` method of table to set model. Still the problem exists. please provide me the sample code.

Comment: something wrong with the code you are _not_ showing :-) Or in other words: add a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: -1 and voting to close because you still don't show a SSCCE, without the question is not answerable

Comment: @kleopatra friend, i new to stackoverflow account. i dont have enough reputation to upload a picture. that why i explained a short code to you

Comment: not talking about an image, but a **SSCCE** (your favourite search engine is your friend in case you don't know what that is ;-)

Comment: anyhow i solved it. write now i got trap in a new problem. would you suggest solution? i have jtable which have 20 rows. sometimes some 3 or 4 rows become empty. my user dont want to see empty or unfilled rows.? i think this could help you to provide me solution...

Comment: new problem - new question (and don't forget the SSCCE :-)

Comment: shall i edit the above question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default type of values stored in a table are of the object type. Try converting it first to a "String" type (or so as required), and then storing it in the array.

Comment: i converted string to object the dataValues[][] after defining the DefaultTableModel and setting it to jtable, .txt file not loading, before inserting d code it was loaded!?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample code you requested.  This works without error:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class TableDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String columnNames[] = {" BIN", " NAME", " SECURITY CODE"};
            String dataValues[][] = new String[15][3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    dataValues[i][j] = Integer.toString(i) + "," + Integer.toString(j);
                }
            }

            JTable table = new JTable();
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dataValues, columnNames);
            table.setModel(model);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            frame.getContentPane().add(table);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

If this doesn't help, please post the contents of your dataValues and columnNames arrays.

Comment: when I use table.setModel(model) in my code, the file content not loading to the jtable seriously what to do?

Comment: String columnNames[] = { " BIN", " NAME", " SECURITY CODE" };final String dataValues[][] = new String[15][3]; for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
     {
      for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
       dataValues[i][j]=cName[k];

}}

Comment: @arvind, The code from above is NOT a SSCCE.

Comment: I updated the Answer to be an SSCCE.